# How to configure custom maven project structure

Tags: java, maven, build, jenkins

I know that typically maven structure is like this:

```
 pom.xml
 src
   - main
   - web
    - WEB-INF
```

However, I have a project which has the following structure

```
src
  - main
web
  - WEB-INF
```

The latter of the two above currently does not use maven. I've started using maven for this project locally by making the structure conform to the maven standard. However, I now want to automatically build this project from jenkins by getting it out of the source control (svn). So I would like to just add a pom.xml which is aware of the fact that `web` isn't inside `src`

Is this possible to do with maven?

Comment: Why don't you just commit your local changes to svn?

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the [`maven-war-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) to use another [`warSourceDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory) but as Jeff Storey explains in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390266/1350762) it is really not recommended.

This is how you would do it:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

One of several problems is for example that the [`maven-jetty-plugin`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) will not run out-of-the-box. It will by default look in `src/main/webapp` so that has to be configured.

You might not use the `maven-jetty-plugin` but you get the idea.

Comment: This would be acceptable as long as the war is created. Right now the war is being created, however, with the above changes you suggested the WAR isn't including my src classes.

Comment: @birdy Where is your source? `src/main/java` or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Using the maven war plugin properties, you can set the `warSourceDirectory` property http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html (I'm not sure exactly what problems you're having, so this may or may not solve your specific problem).

However, maven is very opinionated and I would strongly recommend using the expected maven structure. Other plugins may give you unexpected problems down the road, and maven life is generally a lot easier when you follow their conventions.

Comment: Your link is linking back to this question.

Comment: But now you are linking to an old Maven 1.x version of the war.