# Path to Web Ressource Directory is changed when I run JavaEE project through Maven

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a simple JavaEE Web Application which runs just fine from `intellij` on a `tomcat server(v. 8.5.15)`.

I'd like to manage dependencies with maven and so when I add a pom file with the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` and run the web-project with tomcat7:run i get a 404 when i try to visit `localhost:8080/index.jsp`.

It seems as though `tomcat7:run` changes my Web Ressource Directory(where it finds my `WEB-INF` folder and my `index.jsp` file) to `src/main/webapp` - which doesn't exist. Therefore it can't find the `index.jsp`. But I can't find out how/why the directory gets changed - has anybody here got a clue about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390239/how-to-configure-custom-maven-project-structure may be helpful

Comment: @mikep thank you - it looks to be exactly what I need :)

Comment: @mikep it did the job :)! I doesn't though, seem as though I can give you credit for answering my question because you answered in a comment :(

Comment: Glad I could help.  It wouldn't be right to submit a link as an answer.